# Is there a penalty for killing citizens?

Tags: the-ascent

When roaming around the populated streets of The Ascent, there are instances of enemy encounters in high-civilian-density areas. After a certain point in the story, you are connected with a character named Kira. After intentionally, or accidentally, killing citizens, Kira will ping me about how killing the citizens of your Arcology is bad and conspicuous. There are multiple messages from her giving differing warnings, however actual consequences for killing citizens haven't been encountered.

So, is there any penalty for killing civilians, either intentionally or accidentally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just completed the game, there does not appear to have been any penalty. Kira makes another comment towards the end about my "lack of murderous finesse", but otherwise, there doesn't appear to be any consequences for wanton murder, nor any reward for avoiding it.